# Use a boost converter with power bank and Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I've tried to power my Raspberry Pi 3 Model B by means a Catlyn Power Bank 10000mah.

The Raspberry Pi starts but a low voltage warning is showed.

I've understood that through USB cable there is a voltage drop below the initial 5V of the power bank and, for this reason, I receive the low voltage warning.

I've read on the web that could I use a boost converter that, I think, should stabilize the voltage to the required 5.1 V whatever happens.

The questions are:

(1) Is this a good and safe idea?

(2) If so, what kind of converter must I build?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: you probably want a boost/buck converter, since the output is so close to the input. you can get a cheap module online, so there shouldn't be anything to build per se.

Comment: Power bank already have step-up converter. Battery voltage 3.7V. You may try to change output voltage a little.